# Does being principal ideal ring with identity implies PID?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, principal-ideal-domains, integral-domain

I have recently stumbled upon a standard proof that if $R$ is a Euclidean ring, then $R$ is a PID. But in the proof they first show that $R$ is a principal ideal ring with identity. But then they deduce that thus $R$ is a PID without further explanation. In particular, I cannot see why $R$ is an integral domain. It has identity, commutative, but cannot see why it does not have zero divisors. (Proof from Hungerford's Algebra book)

Comment: Usually a Euclidean ring is assumed to be an integral domain, and is called a "Euclidean domain". Are they doing this implicitly?

Comment: They called it a Euclidean ring and explicitly mentioned that when the ring is an integral domain, then it is called a Euclidean domain

Comment: @User666x it's probably just a typo then

Comment: Yes, seems like it. Thanks guys

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. There are lots of principal ideal rings (with identity) that are not domains.

For example, $F_2[x]/(x^2)$ where $F_2$ is the field of two elements, or even more simply $\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z$.

Also $F_2\times F_2$, since I have an ongoing thing where I try to use this whenever it applies.